# Is there a way to power a computer stick from my phone with OTG?

Tags: usb-c, otg

I need a compute stick like the Intel compute stick with me on the go. The way I will access it is just by doing SSH. I need a way to power it up, either by power bank or by my own phone via OTG, preferably OTG. My phone has USB type c 3.1, but I can only find OTG cables that go up to 3.0. I for example found this one:

[image: Product]

It says 3A max, and as far as I know OTG is 5V. This makes it 15W, which an Intel compute stick would need. Does this mean I can go with his?

Answer (score 1):

I would think your phone has more of a problem to provide the 15W output than the cable has to handle it. My suggestion would be to go with a power bank as those are meant to output that kind of power.

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy s10, which is of USB type c 3.1, from the official Samsung page.

Comment: Do they state what the OTG supply capability is? My guess would be not more 500mA but I have absolutely no data to back that claim up.

Comment: No they do not state it anywhere as far as I can see